# Intellectual Property infringement

Tags: time-travel

My name is George.  I am the true creator of peanut butter.  Since my discovery, I fell into a time vortex that landed me in 2014 where I have found that my old rival has taken credit for my idea.  I've spent the last 2 years trying to figure out a way to bring justice to my name, and though I have found myself in the future, most of your society still doesn't believe in time travel.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to prove this kind of intellectual property (includes patents and trade marks) infringement?

Comment: The original invention was made in or shortly prior to 1890? Time matters here because the survival rate of evidence is probably inversely related to it.

Comment: You mean patent infringement or something else, right? You can't copyright peanut butter.

Comment: You can't patent peanut butter either. Trade secrets are pretty much the entire game when it comes to intellectual property related to food preparation, and when a rival gets your secrets, there is rarely much you can do about it. Also, copyrights and patents expire with time, so moving forward in time automatically makes your IP less valuable.

Comment: Try watching Flash of Genius.

Answer (score 12):

First off, you are talking about an industrial product or process (making peanut butter), which is covered by patents, not copyrights or trademarks. (Copyrights are for published books, musical works, movies and similar things, while trademarks are for the identifiers of products, such as trade names. "Hook and Loop fasteners" is a term used these days since Velcro is the actual trademarked name of the product. Unless Velcro actually made the stuff, you can't refer to it as "Velcro").

That out of the way, what you need is some proof that:

a. You are, in fact the inventor of peanut butter

b. Your patent exists prior to the claimed date of invention

c. Your patent has not expired

Proof that you are the inventor of peanut butter is going to be difficult. Somehow you are going to have to produce laboratory notebooks, patent applications, correspondence with investors or other parties or other documentation demonstrating your prior claim. These documents need to be authenticated somehow to demonstrate they are not clever forgeries (and there is the additional problem that you are obviously not 200 years old or however old you would be if you were the inventor of peanut butter). If you are working on behalf of the inventor of peanut butter (you tell everyone you are a grandchild or nephew of the inventor), then you at least avoid that problem.

Lots of people *invented* things, but credit goes to the person who filed the patent first (and had the patent accepted). Unless you are a polymath like Leonardo da Vinci, who's detailed drawings anticipated tanks, flying machines, submarines, diving suits and so on over 500 years prior to the large scale adoption of these devices, most people are going to dismiss you as a crank, or at the very least as a poor loser who submitted the application second. (Note in the case of Leonardo, he at least fulfills condition one. *No one* disputes his primacy in these fields).

Finally, patents expire after a set time (traditionally it was 20 years but can vary with the country). You may be able to document your claim, but if the patent expiry has passed, you will be out of luck claiming any royalties for this.

For the record, most people agree that [Dr. John Harvey Kellogg](http://infogalactic.com/info/John_Harvey_Kellogg) invented peanut butter in its modern form. Indeed, the National Peanut Board states that Kellogg received a patent in 1896. Good luck overturning that claim....

Edit to add link to Kellogg's biographical information.

Comment: Prior to 2013, the United States used a "first to invent" standard, not "first to file".

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to write something about that. (BTW: I didn't know the US changed, that is very good to know; "first to invent" is a nightmare.) For those who don't know what those two terms mean, they are basically two different ways of determining who gets priority if two people apply for the same patent. Most of the world use "first to file", i.e. the one who files the application first wins (note: days are considered to be indivisible, so if person 1 files 0:01 in the morning, and person 2 files 23:59 in the night, they will *both* get a shared patent – I don't know if this has …

Comment: … ever actually happened, though). The other possibility is "first to invent", i.e. the one who first made the invention wins. This is in some sense fairer to the first inventor, but it is an absolute nightmare to handle. It can also lead to the situation where someone keeps their invention secret, waits till someone else makes the same invention and patents it, let *them* go through all the hard work of productizing and marketing it, and *then* all of a sudden surface from the dark and show their earlier invention and thus invalidate the patent. First to file may not be "fair" in that …

Comment: sense, but it is much easier to determine.

Answer (score 3):

You'd need some kind of documentation of the discovery that didn't travel through time with you.

It sounds as though, for some inexplicable reason, you didn't bother taking any precautions for normal, forseeable events like storms, floods, and rips in the space/time continuum, so I doubt you have a safe deposit box at a bank or similar. You might be able to find your old safe with your original recipe and notes in it, if your rival didn't use his treacherous minions to track it down while he twirled his mustache; these would be ideal.

You may also be able to find something in a bureaucratic organization's archives. Lawyers, for example, could well have kept very old correspondence.

Even if you can prove your claim, however, don't count on easy riches. The Peanut Butter Cabal is powerful, and you'd have to prove not only that you invented it, but that you are the same person as the one in the documents. Since peanut butter was patented in 1884, and you have no doubt been declared legally dead in the mean time, you're not likely to get anyone to accept you as the true inventor of peanut butter.

Also, even if you prove your case, it's likely to get you no more than a quiet mention in the history books. Look up the case of Antonio Meucci, who claimed to have invented the telephone. His work was done long before Alexander Graham Bell's 'invention', but he was unable to afford the fee to maintain his copyright on the invention. When it lapsed, Bell snatched it up and filed his own patent. Even today, after the US Congress has passed a resolution effectively recognizing Meucci as the inventor of the telephone, his name is little more than a footnote in history.

Comment: Re: your last paragraph: in Germany, it is actually usually taught that Philipp Reis invented the telephone in 1860. Reis made several improvements to his telephone and started to "mass" produce demonstration prototypes which he sold to universities around the world. In 1862, Alexander Graham Bell studied one of Reis's early models in Edinburgh, and in 1875, the Smithsonian Institute acquired a much newer and improved model, which Bell also studied; in addition, he also studied both Reis's and Meucci's articles on the subject. Then, and only then, did he "invent" the telephone.

Comment: BTW: some things in your last paragraph are confusing: you say Meucci "was unable to afford the fee to maintain his copyright on the invention", but you cannot copyright an invention.

Comment: Yes, I'm glossing over quite a bit of detail there, because it's a very complicated mess with a lot of twists and turns. Meucci had a 'caveat' on the invention, sort of a temporary placeholder while the patent itself was being pursued. It lasted for a year, but could be extended for another year for a payment of $10. He didn't have the money to pay for that extension, and Bell filed a patent of his own, based on Meucci's work, as soon as it expired.